# What happened to commerce_discounts->saveDiscounts or How to relate vouchers to product types in Commerce 2?

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce2

We sell vouchers to our shop users. To prevent them for being used on vouchers themself, i could relate them to specific productTypes or even products in Commerce 1.

```
craft()->commerce_discounts->saveDiscount($discount, $groups, $productTypes, $products)
```

In Commerce 2 the 3rd and 4th parametes are gone. How can i relate vouchers to product types programmaticely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You now need to set the groups, product types, and purchasables on the discount model directly, then just pass the discount model to the saveDiscount method:

`Plugin::getInstance()->getDiscounts()->saveDiscount($discount)`

An example of setting these things on the discount before saving can be found in the discount controller:

https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/blob/develop/src/controllers/DiscountsController.php#L128-L166

Comment: Ok , so this would be $discount->setCategoryIds($productTypes); in my case. Thanks a lot!